# Modify program to encrypt both uppercase and lowercase input

Tags: c++, encryption, random, shuffle, alphabet

I have to write code for a random cipher problem. I have done it, but the program transforms only uppercase or lowercase (depending on what I choose) letters as input. What should I change so that the program transforms both upper and lower-case letters?

code:

```
   srand(time(0));     //seed for rand()
static char alphabet[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
string alph="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const int LENGTH=sizeof(alphabet)-1;     

int r;
char temp;
for (unsigned int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)   //loop which shuffles the array
{
    r=rand() % LENGTH;  
    temp=alphabet[i];         
    alphabet[i] = alphabet[r];  
    alphabet[r]=temp;   
}

string text;
getline (cin, text);
for (unsigned int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)     //loop to encrypt
{
    if (isalpha(text[i]))
    {
        text[i]=alphabet[text[i] - 'A'];    //index alphabet with the value of text[i], adjusted to be in the range 0-25

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Added full code (also for decryption of this substitution cipher)**

Add second alphabet of lowercase characters and modify it in the same loop which shuffles array of first alphabet like:

```
temp=alphabet_of_lowerCase[i];         
alphabet_of_lowerCase[i] = alphabet_of_lowerCase[r];  
alphabet_of_lowerCase[r]=temp;
```

Now in your encryption scheme just check if symbol is lowercase or uppercase letter with `islower` is `isupper` functions and use required alphabet array accordingly inside `isalpha` if branch:

```
if (islower()) {
   text[i]= alphabet_of_lowerCase[text[i] - 'a'];
}
else
   // your previous code
```

Full code:

```
static char alphabet[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
static char text[] = "TEST";

void shuffleAlphabet() {

    srand(time(0));     //seed for rand()

    const int LENGTH = sizeof(alphabet)-1;

    int r;
    char temp;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)   //loop which shuffles the array
    {
        r=rand() % LENGTH;
        temp=alphabet[i];
        alphabet[i] = alphabet[r];
        alphabet[r]=temp;
    }

}

void cipher(int decrypt) {

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<strlen(text); i++)     //loop to encrypt
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            if (!decrypt)
                text[i]=alphabet[text[i] - 'A'];    //index alphabet with the value of text[i], adjusted to be in the range 0-25
            else {
                int charPos = strchr(alphabet, text[i]) - alphabet; // calculate character position in cipher alphabet
                text[i]='A' + charPos; // and advance forward in standard alphabet by this position
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    printf("Text: %s\n", text);
    shuffleAlphabet();
    printf("Cipher alphabet: %s\n", alphabet);
    cipher(0);
    printf("Encrypted: %s\n", text);
    cipher(1);
    printf("Decrypted: %s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

So in general you need only to know cipher alphabet used to decipher encrypted text. Actually you don't have to even know cipher alphabet to
decode encrypted text, because you can use [frequency analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) for breaking almost all substitution ciphers (including XOR encryption).
Unless ... key used in substitution cipher is with same length as size of original text and is always random,- in this case we will get unbreakable [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

Comment: Ahh, this solves it! Thank you, wish I had thought of it earlier. Have a great day!

Comment: Also, would it be possible to decrypt a message using this random cipher? It confuses me as I don't have a key to the cipher so I have no idea how a decryption code should look like for this program.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include decryption part - check it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `std::transform()` algorithm function, with a lambda that returns the upper or lower case character transformation.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
//...
std::string text;
//...
std::transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), [](char c) 
  { return isupper(c)?tolower(c):toupper(c); });
```

Live Example:  http://ideone.com/PJmc1b

The `std::transform` function is named `transform` for a reason, and the above is an example.  We take the string, iterate over it, and "transform" each character from lower to upper (or vice-versa).  The lambda function is the rule to apply to each character in the string.